# Plotting the proportion of each of one feature that contain a specific value of another feature

Tags: python, matplotlib, crosstab

I have a data frame with multiple features, including two categorical:  'race' (5 unique values) and 'income' (2 unique values:  <=$50k and >$50k)

I've figured out how to do a cross-tabulation table between the two.

However, I can't figure out a short way on how to create a table or bar graph that shows what percentage of each of the five races falls in the <=$50k income group

The code below gives me a table where the rows are the individual races; the counts for each of the two categories of income; and the total counts for each race.  I can't figure out how to add another column on the right that simply takes the count for <=$50k, divides by the total, and then lists the proportion

```
  ct_race_income=pd.crosstab(adult_df.race, adult_df.income, margins=True)
```

Here's a bunch of code where I do it the long way:  calculating each proportion and then creating a new dataframe for the purposes of making a bar chart.  However, I want to code all of this in many fewer lines

```
  total_white=len(adult_df[adult_df.race=="White"])
  total_black=len(adult_df[adult_df.race=="Black"])
  total_hisp=len(adult_df[adult_df.race=="Hispanic"])
  total_asian=len(adult_df[adult_df.race=="Asian"])
  total_amer_indian=len(adult_df[adult_df.race=="Amer-Indian"])

  prop_white=(len(adult_df_lowincome[adult_df_lowincome.race=="White"])/total_white)
  prop_black=(len(adult_df_lowincome[adult_df_lowincome.race=="Black"])/total_black)
  prop_hisp=(len(adult_df_lowincome[adult_df_lowincome.race=="Hispanic"])/total_hisp)
  prop_asian=(len(adult_df_lowincome[adult_df_lowincome.race=="Asian"])/total_asian)
  prop_amer_indian=(len(adult_df_lowincome[adult_df_lowincome.race=="Amer-Indian"])/total_amer_indian)

  prop_lower_income=pd.DataFrame()
  prop_lower_income['Race']=["White","Black","Hispanic", "Asian", "American Indian"]
  prop_lower_income['Ratio']=[prop_white, prop_black, prop_hisp, prop_asian, prop_amer_indian]
```